# Вывод N слов из массива

Tags: php

Привет.

Мне необходимо из массива слов выводить случайные N слов без повторений. Количество слов указывает пользователь.

Подозреваю что проще всего реализовать на php, но я в нем совсем плох, посему прошу помощи коллективного разума или напутствий в какую сторону смотреть.

Спасибо!

Comment: Масив слов имеет повторение?

Comment: Нет. Есть грубо говоря 100 слов, пользователь указывает что ему необходимо вывести 20, выводится 20 рандомных слов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно перемешать массив, и взять первые `N` элементов:

```
function randN(array $src, $n) {
  shuffle($src);
  return array_slice($src, 0, $n);
}
```

Либо воспользоваться функцией [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-rand.php):

```
$keys = array_rand($src, $n);
$result = array_map(function($key) use ($src) {
  return $src[$key];
}, $keys);
```

Или:

```
array_rand(array_flip($src), $n);
```

Comment: Явно что-то делаю не так, вот попытался реализовать по вашим инструкциям, но выдает просто "Array".<?php
$src = array ('Раз' , 'Два' , 'Три' , 'Четыре' , 'Пять' , 'Шесть', 'Семь', 'Восемь');
$n = 3;
$keys = array_rand($src, $n);
$result = array_map(function($key) use ($src) {
  return $src[$key];
}, $keys);

echo $result;

?>

Comment: Вы пытаетесь вывести массив, как строку. Необходимо предварительно сформировать строку. Например так: `echo implode(', ', $result);`

Comment: спасибо большое!